Can I allocate unique_ptr outside the function?
Is this correct? So can I allocate the dynamic var outside the function?
TMyClass* ClassA::myAllocFunc()
{
 return new MyClass;
}

void ClassA::myFunc()
{
 std::unique_ptr<MyClass> l(myAllocFunc);
 
}


Seems like undefined behavior to me. You passed a function pointer to a smart pointer constructor. It doesn't make sense. Maybe you want to call the function like l(myAllocFunc())??

This wont compile so no it is not correct.  Can you be a little more detailed in your question?

The answers to your questions are:  Yes. No. Yes.

Side note: Prefer to use std::make_unique rather than new . make_unique fills in a few holes that can exist between the call to new and the unique_ptr taking ownership that lead to memory leaks.

The unique_ptr<T> constructor needs a pointer to memory allocated with new, it doesn't care (or know) where that pointer came from.

Yes, you can have a function return a raw pointer and have std::unique_ptr take ownership of it.
In your example, you just need to call the function and pass its return value to std::unique_ptr, not try to pass the function itself, eg:
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> l(myAllocFunc()); // <-- notice the extra '()'

That being said, a better option would be to have myAllocFunc() return a std::unique_ptr to begin with, not return a raw pointer, eg:
std::unique_ptr<TMyClass> ClassA::myAllocFunc()
{
    return std::make_unique<MyClass>();
}

void ClassA::myFunc()
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> l = myAllocFunc();
    // or simply:
    // auto l = myAllocFunc();
}

